# django error with postgresql database on real host

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, postgresql-9.1

this is my first python programe to run on server and i have error in database connection.
when i add this line to setting file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'rahepooy_afsoone_db',
        'USER': 'rahepooy_afsoone',
        'PASSWORD': '****************',
    }
}
```

and migrate the code i have error :

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?


if i add "hoset':'IP' to setting.py i have this error :
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column c.relispartition does not exist
LINE 3:             CASE WHEN c.relispartition THEN 'p' WHEN c.relki...
```

and when i go to admin page i got this eror
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUdn7.jpg)
where is my mistake!? and this project is on real host on internet

Comment: Note that Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: this problem cause on real host i dont know the version of Postgres

Comment: it show me all of urls but when i want to go to admin or create user i get this  connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of Django 4, go back to Django 3.2.

```
pip install Django==3.2.12
```

Comment: i change this but not work for me thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
pip install Django==3.2.12 is true
```

I thing is your write less
example：

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': ‘<database_name>’,
       'USER': '<database_username>',
       'PASSWORD': '<password>',
       'HOST': '<database_hostname_or_ip>',
       'PORT': '<database_port>',
    }
}
```